# Fill line chart area with multiple colors

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a chart like below:

[image]

While I've created the skeleton of it but stuck on how to fill those areas with multiple colors. I'm using d3 to complete this chart.
 My code for reference:

```
var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.ind); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.tot_cases); })

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.ind; }));

  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.tot_cases; })]);
  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));



  var lineAndDots = g.append("g")
            .attr("class", "line-and-dots")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + ((margin.left + margin.right) / 3) + "," + 0 + ")")

    // Data line
    lineAndDots.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("class", "data-line")
        .attr("d", line);

    // Data dots
    lineAndDots.selectAll("line-circle")
            .data(data)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "data-circle")
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.ind); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.tot_cases); });

  g.selectAll("lines-ax")
            .data(data)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return x(d.ind) + margin.right; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return height - margin.bottom})
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return x(d.ind) + margin.right ; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return y(d.tot_cases); })
        .attr("fill", "black")
        .attr("stroke", "gray")
        .attr("stroke-width", 3);
```

You can find my entire code in this [link](https://codepen.io/wittybutterfly/pen/mdyYoKK).
Any ideas on how to do this is very helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a clean implementation, since I did not implement `select, enter, append` pattern of D3, also I add a random color generator, I will leave it to you to clean it up and add your color scheme to the chart

**You might notice that the last element missing its color and polygon item since there is no indication on how to add it.**

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);
var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = [
  {"ind": "Examined", tot_cases: 25000},
  {"ind": "Notified", tot_cases: 17000},
  {"ind": "Initiated", tot_cases: 10000},
  {"ind": "HIV Stat. Confirmed", tot_cases: 14000},
  {"ind": "HIV Unknown", tot_cases:15000}
]

var stroke_colors = {
  "Examined": '#2B597C',
  "Notified": "#6D5C7E",
  "Initiated": '#BF6D84',
  "HIV Stat. Confirmed": '#F1737E',
  "HIV Unknown": '#F9B294'
}

var color = ["#2B597C","#6D5C7E","#BF6D84","#F1737E","#F9B294"]

  var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.ind); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.tot_cases); })

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.ind; }));

  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.tot_cases; })]);

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));



  var lineAndDots = g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "line-and-dots")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + ((margin.left + margin.right) / 3) + "," + 0 + ")")

    // Data line
    lineAndDots.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("class", "data-line")
        .attr("d", line)
        .style('stroke', function(d){ 
              for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
             return stroke_colors[d[i].ind];}})
        .style('fill', 'none')

    // Data dots
    lineAndDots.selectAll("line-circle")
      .data(data)
     .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "data-circle")
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.ind); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.tot_cases); })

  g.selectAll("lines-ax")
      .data(data)
     .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return x(d.ind) + margin.right; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return height})
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return x(d.ind) + margin.right ; })
        .attr("fill", "black")
        .attr("stroke", "#F2F2F2")
        .attr("stroke-width", 3);

  

  for(let i=1; i< data.length; i++) {
    let points = [];
    points[0] = {x: x(data[i-1].ind) + margin.right, y: y(data[i-1].tot_cases)};
    points[1] = {x: x(data[i].ind) + + margin.right, y: y(data[i].tot_cases)};
    points[2] = {x: x(data[i].ind) + + margin.right, y: height};
    points[3] = {x: x(data[i-1].ind) + margin.right, y: height};
    points[4] = {x: x(data[i-1].ind) + margin.right, y: y(data[i-1].tot_cases)};
    g.append("polygon")
    .attr("points",  points.map(function(d) { return [d.x,d.y].join(","); }).join(" "))
    .attr("stroke","red")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr('fill', getRandomRgb());
  }

  let points = [];
  points[0] = {x: x(data[data.length - 1].ind) + margin.right, y: y(data[data.length - 1].tot_cases)};

  points[1] = {x: x(data[data.length - 1].ind) + margin.right + 150, y: y(data[data.length - 1].tot_cases)};
  points[2] = {x: x(data[data.length - 1].ind) + margin.right + 150, y: height};

  points[3] = {x: x(data[data.length - 1].ind) + margin.right, y: height};
  points[4] = {x: x(data[data.length - 1].ind) + margin.right, y: y(data[data.length - 1].tot_cases)};

  g.append("polygon")
    .attr("points",  points.map(function(d) { return [d.x,d.y].join(","); }).join(" "))
    .attr("stroke","red")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr('fill', getRandomRgb());

  function getRandomRgb() {
    const num = Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random());
    const r = num >> 16;
    const g = num >> 8 & 255;
    const b = num & 255;
    return 'rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')';
  }
```

```css
body {  
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;  
}
  
.axis {
 font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
  
text {
  fill: #727075;
  stroke: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: none;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.grid path {
  stroke: none;
}

.grid line {
  stroke: #E0E0E0;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
  
.data-line {
  fill: none; 
stroke: url(#line-gradient);
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
  
.data-circle {
 fill: #3C92BA;     
}
  
.axis-title {
 text-anchor: end;
  fill: #5D6971;
  font-weight: normal;
}
  
.axis-tspan {
 font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      

      </style>
  </head>
<body>
  <svg width="960" height="500"></svg>

  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @SPL I add the color for the last element, check it!